# Is it possible to have DropDown with Check Box in Oracle Forms?

Tags: oracle10g, oracleforms

I had a doubt that can we have Checkbox in Dropdown in Oracle Forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a native control within Oracle Forms that allows a check box within a List Of Values (LOV)

However you may be able to use Plugable Java Components (PJC) to build a more appropriate control.

Here is a  [page](http://forms.pjc.bean.over-blog.com/)  that I have found very useful for help with PJC's